# More Epoch make loss rising

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, time-series, lstm

I have a time-series dataset and I trained it using LSTM. I train using 200 epochs and the result is the loss value and val_loss value is pretty good (IMO)

[image]

then I think the result still can be better if I add more epochs so I retrain using 400 epochs. but the loss and val_loss is rising [image]

but somehow the result is different. even become worse. is it better still to use the 200 epoch model or there really is a condition if more epochs can worsen the model

Comment: Try to give more information like the  architecture of the model and the type of data

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because your lr(learning rate) is too large. You could try to reduce your lr. From the graph, the training loss is increased so I think this case is not the problem of overfitting.

Comment: Start from reducing your lr at least 10 times small. If not work, plz provide more info thanks.